# Look for a word and copy row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I keep getting a mix of two errors: Runtime Error '5941' The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist and Object variable not set (Error 91) for this code.

I am trying to look for a word in tables 8 and 9 in the document and if found, copy and paste its corresponding row in a new doc.

```
Dim z As Long
Dim v As Long
Dim Table As Table
Dim Tables As Tables
Dim Rows As Rows
Dim Row As Row

For z = 8 To 9 Step 1
    For v = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows.Count Step 1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows(v).Select
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="apples"
            If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
                ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows(v).Select
                Selection.Copy
                ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "C:".Activate
                Selection.EndKey wdStory
                Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
            End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: which are the lines you get the error? `Dim Table As Table` and similar: you should NEVER define a variable overwriting a variable's name.

Comment: The lines giving the error are  For v = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows.Count Step 1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows(v).Select

Comment: what happens if you delete the lines: Dim Table As Table and similar?

Comment: Now I get the error 5941  The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist for line For v = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Rows.Count Step 1

Comment: Are you sure that `ActiveDocument` is the document with 9 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code - you should be more explicit regarding the documents you are working on:

```vb
Sub copyRowsWithApples()

Dim docSource As Word.Document
Set docSource = ThisDocument    'adjust this e.g. ActiveDocument if applicable.

Dim docTarget As Word.Document
Set docTarget = Application.Documents.Add   'adjust this to your settings

Dim z As Long

Dim tbl As Table
Dim tblRow As Row

For z = 8 To 9 Step 1
    Set tbl = docSource.Tables(z)
    
    For Each tblRow In tbl.Rows
        With tblRow.Range.Find
                .Execute findtext:="apples"
                If .Found = True Then
                    tblRow.Range.Copy
                    
                    With docTarget.Content
                        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        .PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
                    End With
    
                End If
        End With
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: One question I have and I know this is probably very stupid but I am very new with VBA. How do I set the target document as an existing document?

Comment: look into  `Application.Documents.Open`